# Effective Repository in C# - Where to put methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

I'm trying to build a new application using the Repository pattern for the first time and I'm a little confused about using a Repository.  Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public class Ticket
{

}
public class User
{
   public List<Ticket>AssignedTickets { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
   public List<User> GroupMembers { get;set; }
   public List<Ticket> GroupAssignedTickets { get;set; }
}
```

I need a methods that can populate these collections by fetching data from the database.

I'm confused as to which associated Repository class I should put those methods in.  Should I design my repositories so that everything *returning* type T goes in the repository for type T as such?

```
public class TicketRepository
{
   public List<Ticket> GetTicketsForGroup(Group g) { }
   public List<Ticket> GetTicketsForUser(User u) { }
}
public class UserRepository
{
  public List<User> GetMembersForGroup(Group g) { }
}
```

The obvious drawback I see here is that I need to start instantiating a lot of repositories.  What if my User also has assigned Widgets, Fidgets, and Lidgets?  When I populate a User, I need to instantiate a WidgetRepository, a FidgetRepository, and a LidgetRepository all to populate a single user.

Alternatively, do I construct my repository so that everything requesting based on type T is lumped into the repository for type T as listed below?

```
public class GroupRepository
{
    public List<Ticket> GetTickets(Group g) { }
    public List<User> GetMembers(Group g) { }
}
public class UserRepository
{
   public List<Ticket> GetTickets(User u) { }
}
```

The advantage I see here is that if I now need my user to have a collection of Widgets, Fidgets, and Lidgets, I just add the necessary methods to the UserRepository pattern and don't need to instantiate a bunch of different repository classes every time I want to create a user, but now I've scattered the concerns for a user across several different repositories.

I'm really not sure which way is right, if any.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the first option was the more practical option in this case.  There were a few reasons for this:

1) When making changes to a type and its associated repository (assume Ticket), it was *far* easier to modify the Ticket and TicketRepository in one place than to chase down every method in every repository that used a Ticket.

2) When I attempted to use interfaces to dictate the type of queues each repository could pull, I ran into issues where a single repository couldn't implement an generic interface using type T multiple times with the only differentiation in interface method implementation being the parameter type.

3) I access data from SharePoint and a database in my implementation, and created two abstract classes to provide data tools to the concrete repositories for either Sharepoint or SQL Server. Assume that in the example above Users come from Sharepoint while Tickets come from a database.  Using my model I would not be able to use these abstract classes, as the group would have to inherit from both my Sharepoint abstract class and my SQL abstract class.  C# does not support multiple inheritance of abstract classes. However, if I'm grouping all Ticket-related behaviours into a TicketRepository and all User-related behaviours into a UserRepository, each repository only needs access to one type of underlying data source (SQL or Sharepoint, respectively).

Answer (score 4):

The repository pattern can help you to:

> Put things that change for the same reason together

As well as

> Separate things that change for different reasons

On the whole, I would expect a "User Repository" to be a repository for obtaining users. Ideally, it would be the only repository that you can use to obtain users, because if you change stuff, like user tables or the user domain model, you would only need to change the user repository. If you have methods on many repositories for obtaining a user, they would all need to change.

Limiting the impact of change is good, because change is inevitable.

As for instantiating many repositories, using a dependency injection tool such as Ninject or Unity to supply the repositories, or using a repository factory, can reduce new-ing up lots of repositories.

Finally, you can take a look at the concept of Domain Driven Design to find out more about the key purpose behind domain models and repositories (and also about aggregate roots, which are relevant to what you are doing).

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating question with no right answer.  This might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com rather than stackoverflow.com.  Here are my thoughts:

Don't worry about creating too many repositories.  They are basically stateless objects so it isn't like you will use too much memory.  And it shouldn't be a significant burden to the programmer, even in your example.

The real benefit of repositories is for mocking the repository for unit testing.  Consider splitting them up based on what is simplest for the unit tests, to make the dependency injection simple and clear.  I've seen cases where every query is a repository (they call those "queries" instead of repositories).  And other cases where there is one repository for everything.

Comment: "This might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com rather than stackoverflow.com."...while it is one of my favorite tags here, what you have stated is probably true of the entire `design-patterns` tag.  I've always been surprised that the whole group hasn't been relocated yet.  Design pattern questions are almost always subjective.